# Function from on click is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic website that plays a sound when you click but the onclick method from the index.php is undefined and i cant find the error.

Error report is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Train is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):46)

But I don't understand what I referenced wrong can someone explain it?

note: script is referenced i have a same button with traffic as name and that one works

```js
function Traffic() {}
function Talking() {}
function Bar() {}
function Train() {
  var sound = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
  var gif = "https://thumbs.gfycat.com/CoarseSimpleCutworm-size_restricted.gif";
  var info = this.name;
  trainBoolean = true;
  Execute(sound, gif, info);
}


function Execute(audio, image, imageInfo) {

  body.innerHTML = "";
  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", image);
  x.setAttribute("width", width);
  x.setAttribute("height", height);
  x.setAttribute("alt", imageInfo);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

  audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }, false);
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:10%;" scope="col">#</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">Street</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">People</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">Places</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Traffic()" class="btn btn-warning">Traffic</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Talking()" class="btn btn-warning">Talking</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Bar()" class="btn btn-warning">Bar</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Train()" class="btn btn-warning">Train</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="" class="btn btn-warning">2</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Stadion()" class="btn btn-warning">Stadion</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Construction()" class="btn btn-warning">Construction</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="" class="btn btn-warning">2</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Disco()" class="btn btn-warning">Disco</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you import the `script.js` file somewhere in `index.php`? Something like: `<script src='js/script.js'></script>`. That would be one reason. Another one could be that your function `Train` is not accessible at the document level (e.g. when you define it inside an object).

Comment: Did you reference `script.js` in `index.php` correctly? Can you call `Train` from the console?

Comment: can you show the header of your index.php? most probably, the reason is in your imports.

Comment: script is refrenced correctly Traffic() onclick works

Comment: I get "body is not defined" in the [mcve] I made fo you

Comment: But `document.body.innerHTML = "";` is a VERY bad idea if you have your script in the body tag!

Comment: When I fix that, I have issues with width and height are undefined

Comment: Removing `body.innerHTML = ""` and adding `var width = 200, height=200;` to your function makes the script work

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @Cid the functions are not run until clicked

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Traffic() {}
function Talking() {}
function Bar() {}
function Train() {
  var sound = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
  var gif = "https://thumbs.gfycat.com/CoarseSimpleCutworm-size_restricted.gif";
  var info = this.name;
  trainBoolean = true;
  Execute(sound, gif, info);
}


function Execute(audio, image, imageInfo,width,height) {

  
  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", image);
  x.setAttribute("width", width);
  x.setAttribute("height", height);
  x.setAttribute("alt", imageInfo);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

  audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }, false);
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:10%;" scope="col">#</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">Street</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">People</th>
          <th style="width:30%;" scope="col">Places</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Traffic()" class="btn btn-warning">Traffic</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Talking()" class="btn btn-warning">Talking</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Bar()" class="btn btn-warning">Bar</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Train()" class="btn btn-warning">Train</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="" class="btn btn-warning">2</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Stadion()" class="btn btn-warning">Stadion</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Construction()" class="btn btn-warning">Construction</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="" class="btn btn-warning">2</button>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
                <button onclick="Disco()" class="btn btn-warning">Disco</button>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```